# Gnome shell extention ubuntu dock

Tags: 20.04, gnome, mount, hard-drive, display

This bug [ubuntu dock not removing unmounted dvd/cd drives](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1856032)
Is marked as fixed, but in ubuntu 20.04 it still seams to be bugged, is there any way I can update this, or fix it, even if its a workaround, that would be nice (for anyone who suggests to just disable all drives on the task bar, I dont wish to do this, I just dont want this to appear while unmounted, and I cannot find a way to disable showing on the taskbar for only one drive)

(also this is my first time using this site, so sorry if any of the info is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

According to [The package details](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock), `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` on 20.04 is at version `67ubuntu20.04.5`, which is an outdated version.

> This should be fixed by `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` **`72~ubuntu1`**. -- Marco Trevisan

The bug is only fixed on `72~ubuntu1` and further versions. So, upgrade your Ubuntu to 22.04 to use a newer version of Ubuntu Dock (`72~ubuntu5`).